# Finding the library that defines a given C function

Tags: c, linker, standard-library

On a Linux distribution (e.g. Debian) how does one find the static library or shared object that defines a given function (e.g. printf)? Is some variation of (first using ldd from a given executable that uses that function and then using something like nm -D --defined-only /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6  | grep printf | more) the right way to do it?

Comment: Hack: `man 3 <funcname>`, assuming that the library is well-documented.

Comment: And if nothing it mentioned it's in the Standard Library ("libc").